# Different name servers for different subdomains

Tags: dns, subdomain, nameservers

Let's say I have a website `example.com` which I bought via a common domain registry `nomcheap.com`.

I want all traffic to a specific subdomain `app.example.com` to go to name server `ns1.appserver.com` so I can serve a specific user app.

I also want all other traffic (`www.example.com`, `hello.example.com`, `*.example.com`, etc.) to go to a different name server from a different provider `ns1.squaresites.com` so I can serve a general website (think something like a commerce Wordpress site).

None of the name servers are provided by the original domain registry `nomcheap.com`.

Is this possible? If so, any suggestions on how?

Comment: In registrar control panel, enter main (root) domain name servers. In main domain name server, add NS records for subdomain name servers.

Comment: Thanks for info, will try this week... Wish folks would leave comment on why they are down-voting honest question

Comment: Probably because it is borderline offtopic

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To point a subdomain to a name servers you need to create an NS record for the subdomain:

`app.example.com NS ns1.appserver.com`

This will make all queries go to `ns1.appserver.com`

`*.example.com   NS ns1.squaresites.com`

The second record should catch all subdomains that don't have their own records (of any kind).

Comment: and when there needs to have ns1,ns2 and ns3 (three nameservers) what to do? DNS ZONE EDITOR has only 1 field when adding NS/A/CNAME record

Comment: Can't you add three different records one at a time?

Comment: To further clarify, should the name servers be ns1.d1.com, ns2.d1.com, ns1.d2.com, ns2.d2.com? Or should they be ns1, ns2, ns3, ns4?

Comment: For me (namecheap.com registrar) it only worked when I had the subdomain "app" as the value, not the full subdomain "app.example.com"

Comment: I have a doubt , suppose in registrar, `example.com` points to some name server. In that name server, `app.example.com` is pointing its NS to `ns1.appserver.com`. does that means during dns resolution, it will go from root -> TLD -> name server -> then see that `app.example.com` wants us to go to `ns1.appserver.com` -> `ns1.appserver.com`will now have an `A` for `app.example.com` ?

Answer (score 4):

Delegating name server DNS responses can be done was the answer by @Lanexbg describes.

Realize that chaining your DNS lookups this way adds more time to DNS resolution and adds another potential point of failure in the resolution process. If the parent's name servers are down, they won't able to deliver the NS records to tell the client's resolver to continue the lookup process through a delegated name server.

Consider if using DNS "A" or "CNAME" records at the parent's DNS server would be acceptable alternative.

For more detail on how DNS resolution is delegated see this answer on serverfault.com:

- [How exactly should I set up DNS to delegate authority for subdomains?](https://serverfault.com/questions/27134/how-exactly-should-i-set-up-dns-to-delegate-authority-for-subdomains)